# Second derivative test without continuity of the second derivative

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, optimization, maxima-minima

Let $S\subset\mathbb{R}$ be an open subset and $f:S\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $f^{''}$ is continuous. Suppose $x_0\in S$ such that $f^{'}(x_0)=0$ and $f^{''}(x_0)>0$, then $x_0$ is a point of local minimum of $f$ by the second derivative test.

I wonder if we remove the continuity assumption of the second derivative function $f^{''}$, can we get $x_0$ is a point of local minimum again or it violates. My guess is that it should violate, since in the proof we use Taylor's theorem, where the continuity of $f^{''}$ is used in the argument.

If it violates, can someone please help with a counter-example of the same?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I see no continuity assumption, only existence of second derivative at critical point, in this reference: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ReciprocalLucasConstant.html

Answer (score 3):

Say $f'(x_0) = 0$ and $f''(x_0) = a > 0$.  No assumption that $f''$ is continuous.  Indeed, no assumption that $f''(x)$ exists for any $x \ne x_0$.

Then
$$
\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f'(x)}{x-x_0} = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f'(x)-f'(x_0)}{x-x_0} = a
$$
Taking $\varepsilon = a/2$ we get $\delta > 0$ so that
$$
|x-x_0| < \delta \quad\Rightarrow\quad\frac{f'(x)}{x-x_0} > \frac{a}{2}
$$
thus, for $x$ with $x_0 < x < x_0+\delta$
$$
f'(x) > (x-x_0)\frac{a}{2} > 0
$$
so $f$ is incrreasing on $(x_0,x_0+\delta)$.
For $x$ with $x_0-\delta < x < x_0$,
$$
f'(x) < (x-x_0)\frac{a}{2} < 0
$$
so $f$ is decreasing on $(x_0-\delta,x_0)$.
Thus $f$ has a local minimum at $x_0$.

Answer (score 1):

In the proof of the sufficient condition for a minimum, all you need is the local Taylor's formula (with remainder in the form of Peano) to be able to say that the quadratic term is the leading one near the point. Taylor's formula in that form only requires the derivatives exist at the given point. Of course, the first derivative has to be continuous in a neighborhood for the second to exist at the point, but only the existence of the second is required at the point in question.

Comment: Thanks. Is it also the case for several variable functions? I mean the second-order partial derivatives do not need not be continuous to guarantee the local minimum from the positive definiteness of the Hessian.

Comment: I like this answer, because it shows how the approach already known to the asker can still be used. As an interesting side note, it's even sufficient if the function is only twice Peano differentiable, for which the existence of $f'$ in a neighborhood is not needed: https://www.jstor.org/stable/44153382

Comment: @Mathguide Yes, this also works for several variable functions. The important thing is that at the suspected extremal point $x$ we have $f(x+h)=f(x)+g(h)+r(h)$, where $g$ has an extremum at $0$ and the remainder  $r$ goes to $0$ faster than $g$ as $h\to0$. In the multidimensional case, $g(h)=h^T\mathrm Hf(x)h$, where $\mathrm Hf(x)$ is the Hessian. And if this Hessian is positive or negative definite, then it has an extremum by definition.

Comment: Thanks. I still have doubt if we really need to assume the continuity of the second-order derivatives in the higher-order Taylors theorem. Because the Taylor series form you mentioned is only proved under the continuity assumption in higher dimension. You may see, for example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Taylor's_theorem_in_one_real_variable   or for example the Calculus II book by Apostol  If you have some reference of the proof of such Taylor form without continuity, please inform me.

Comment: You do not need continuity. Check the form of Peano of the remainder. You just need the correction to the second degree approximation to be negligible (a higher order infinitesimal).